# Java read from text file, getting error on line 21

Tags: java, compiler-errors

How do I pass in the String everything into my new object? I have the .txt file on my desktop. Do I need another method to search for the file?

```
public class ReadFromTextFile {

    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"))) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
            line = br.readLine();
        }
       String everything = sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ReadFromTextFile obj1 = new ReadFromTextFile(everything); // error here
        System.out.println();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Your code is incorrect.

Comment: What error are you getting? Which is line 21?

Comment: It looks like you have one curly brace too much... Wait no, it's worse than that, you have a whole block of code outside of a method?

Comment: There's a lot of issues here. Why are you trying to pass a string into a non-existent method (was that supposed to be a constructor?) and from where are you trying to get the string you're trying to pass?

Comment: @Tunaki There's a lot more wrong than a spurious curly brace...

Comment: and the line 21 is....???

Comment: I have a text file on my desktop i am trying to read the file and print it to the console

Comment: Code outside a method, too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code needs to be rewritten, adding a block of code outside a method is equivalent to doing it into each constructors of your class which is a very bad practice as it is really error prone.

Here is how you could rewrite your code:

```
 public class ReadFromTextFile {

        private final String everything;

        public ReadFromTextFile() throws IOException {
            try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("text.txt"))) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = br.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
                this.everything = sb.toString();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            ReadFromTextFile obj1 = new ReadFromTextFile(); 
            System.out.println(obj1.everything);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: text.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at ReadFromTextFile.<init>(ReadFromTextFile.java:10)
 at ReadFromTextFile.main(ReadFromTextFile.java:25)

Comment: this is the error i get

Comment: The simplest way to fix this is to use an absolute path something like new FileReader("/my/absolute/path/text.txt"). If use a relative path it will be relative to the value of the system property user.dir.

Answer (score 1):

There is no even a constructor in the class  **ReadFromTextFile**
so this statement

```
ReadFromTextFile obj1 = new ReadFromTextFile(everything); /
```

is breaking all the code...

and your try code is missing the catch section

Comment: public ReadFromTextFile(BufferedReader br) {
  super();
  this.br = br;
 }
 would this be the constructor you mentioned?

Comment: yes for example...  and that is not posted in the question's code

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFromTextFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File file = new File("C:/text.txt");
        BufferedReader br;
        String curentLine;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((curentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(curentLine);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This seams to work form me. thanks for the help ;)